# Firebase,iOS: Appending key-value pair into a child node

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following User Table structure in `Firebase`

[image]

As you can see in the user that I have opened, I have a Posts section, inside this post section holds the Id's all articles which have been posted by this user.

The issue I am facing is as follows:

When the user creates a new article it's saved within the Posts Table, after the save I return the newly generated ID which I then pass on to the user table, I trying to insert the newly created ID into the post section of the user, so I assumed the URL would be something like this:

```
Users/{UserId}/Posts
```

However all this does it create a new section called posts, it doesn't actually insert the record into the given area.

My code which isn't working is as follows:

```
let linkPost = [childautoID: true]

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users/\(UserId)/Posts").child(UserId).setValue(linkPost)
```

FYI the two id's that are currently inside Posts I added manually.

I've also tried the following:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users/\(UserId)/Posts").setValue(linkPost)
```

However all this does it remove all existing Id's and then inserts the new id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append a key-value pair in Firebase Database child node use this :-

- Make a Firebase Database Reference to the `Posts` node of that currentUser **`FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("Posts")`**
- Check if `Posts` node exists in your user's DB, If not then create one by :- **`parentRef.setValue([postId : "True"])`** in *else* block.
- But if `Posts` node does exist retrieve it as a **`NSMutableDictionary`** , set the new object to it, and then store the updated Dictionary to that node.

---

```
  func storePostsToDB(postID :String!, userID : String! = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid){

    let parentRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Posts")
    parentRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(friendsList) in

        if friendsList.exists(){
             if let listDict = friendsList.value as? NSMutableDictionary{

                    listDict.setObject("True", forKey: postID)
                    parentRef.setValue(listDict)

                }
        }else{
            parentRef.setValue([postID : "True"])
        }
    })
  }
```

Calling the function:-

```
  storePostsToDB("yourPostID")// If you want to store in the currentUser DB
  storePostsToDB("yourPostID", userID : otherUserID)//If you want to store the post in some other users database with uid `otherUserID`
```

Comment: Hey @Dravidian, apologies on not testing this sooner.  All is working as expected thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer something like this. This automatically append the data without fetching first

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users/\(UserId)/Posts").child(UserId).setValue(true)
```

Comment: Works on latest Swift 3.1. Thanks!